# Optimal substructure in Dynamic Programing

Tags: dynamic-programming

I have been trying to understand Dynamic Programming, and what I understood is that there are two parts of DP.

1. Optimal substructures
2. Overlapping subproblems

I understand the second one, but I am not able to understand the first one.

Answer (score 22):

Optimal substructure means, that any optimal solution to a problem of size `n`, is based on an optimal solution to the same problem when considering `n' < n` elements.

That means, when building your solution for a problem of size `n`, you split the problem to smaller problems, one of them of size `n'`. Now, you need only to consider the optimal solution to `n'`, and not all possible solutions to it, based on the optimal substructure property.

An example is the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem):

```
D(i,k) = min { D(i-1,k), D(i-1,k-weight(i)) + cost(i) }
```

The optimal substructure assumption here, is `D(i,k)` can check only optimal solutions to `D(i-1,k)`, and none optimal solutions are not considered.

An example where this does not hold is the [Vertex Cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover).

If you have a graph G=(V,E), assume you have an optimal solution to a subgraph `G'=(V',E[intersection]V'xV')` such that `V' <= V` - the optimal solution for `G` does not have to be consisted of of the optimal solution for `G'`/

Comment: Does that mean if solution exist for smaller number then optimal substructure exist?

Comment: @amit Can you please tell me if optimal substructure is necessary for a problem to have a DP solution? If this is the case, then how come factorial has a DP solution without (according to my knowledge) having an optimal substructure?

Comment: @Denson They do have optimal substructure, if you are referring to Traveling Salesman Problem, for example, the optimal substructure is on the subsets.

Comment: @amit could you please explain what is the optimal substructure for factorial problem? From what I can understand from your answer subproblem fact(i) will have only one possible solution which will ofcourse be optimal?

Comment: @amit Travelling Salesman Problem having optimal substructure makes sense to me..

Comment: Probably there should be `max` rather than `min` in recurrence relation because in the knapsack problem you are maximizing the value.

Comment: This needs to be explained better, in a simpler manner. Like what is meaning of "needs to consider only optimal solution to n' and not all possible solutions to it". You need to give an example to explain this statement

Answer (score 10):

Another good example is the difference between finding a *shortest* simple path between every pair of vertices in a graph, and finding a *longest* simple path between each of these pairs.  ("Simple" means that no vertex on a path can be visited twice; if we don't put this constraint in for the "longest" version of the problem, then we can get infinitely long paths whenever the graph contains a cycle.)

The [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) can compute the answer to the first problem efficiently by exploiting the fact that, if a path from u to v is shortest-possible, then for any vertex x on this path, it *must* be that the subpath from u to x, and the subpath from x to v, are also shortest-possible.  (Suppose to the contrary that there was a vertex x on the "shortest possible" path from u to v such that the subpath from u to x was not shortest-possible: then it's possible to find some other, shorter path from u to x -- and this can also be used to make the overall path from u to v shorter by the same amount, so the original u-to-v path could not have been shortest-possible after all.)  That means that when looking for the shortest u-to-v path, the algorithm only needs to consider building it out of shortest-possible (that is, optimal) subpaths between other pairs of vertices -- not out of the much larger number of *all* such subpaths.

In contrast, consider the problem of determining the *longest* simple path between any two vertices in a graph.  Is it likewise true that, if the longest path from u to v goes through some vertex x, then the subpaths from u to x, and from x to v, are necessarily also longest-possible?  Unfortunately not: It may well be that the longest path from u to x uses some vertices in its interior that are also needed by the longest path from x to v, meaning that we can't simply glue these two paths together to get a longest *simple* path from u to v.

As a general rule, we can always "get around" this problem by choosing to use a sufficiently detailed definition of the subproblem to be solved: In this case, instead of asking for the longest path between two given vertices u and v, we can ask for the longest path between two given vertices u and v *which uses only vertices from a given set S*.  Where previously we could build a function `shortest(u, v)` that takes two parameters, we must now build a function `longest(u, v, S)` that takes three; the overall longest path between 2 vertices u and v could then be computed using `longest(u, v, V)`, where V is the entire vertex set of the graph.  With this new definition, it's now once again possible to produce optimal solutions by combining only *optimal* solutions to subproblems, because we can ensure that we only try gluing together paths that result from subproblems whose S sets are disjoint.  We can now *correctly* determine the longest path from u to v that uses only vertices in S, namely `longest(u, v, S)`, by calculating the maximum, over all vertices x in S, and all ways of partitioning S-{x} into two subsets A and B, of `longest(u, x, A) + longest(x, v, B)`.

Unfortunately, there are now an exponential number of subproblems to be solved, because a set of n vertices can be partitioned in 2^(n-1) different ways.  (The algorithm just described is not the most efficient possible DP for this problem, but even the most efficient known DP still has this exponential factor in its running time.)  The challenge in designing a DP algorithm is always to find a way to define subproblems that results in *few enough* different subproblems (ideally, only polynomially many) while still maintaining the two properties of overlapping subproblems and optimal substructure.

Comment: For a given problem, How should i find out whether optimal substructure exist or not? is it by hit and trial, solve it for smaller n and then find out, or there is a concrete approach to find it?

Comment: Well, you have to *prove* that optimal substructure is there if you want to use a particular subproblem definition for DP.  But before you try to prove it mathematically, you can try a few examples -- maybe there are some easy counterexamples that will show that it cannot work.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You say that "we can't simply glue these two paths together to get a longest simple path from u to v." Can you give me an example of a graph where this is the case? I can't actually think of one. I'm starting to believe longest path is optimal substructure...

Comment: @Ogen: Firstly and most importantly, the obligation is on you (or whoever wants to try to solve Longest Path using a poly-time DP) to prove that this undesirable situation *can't* happen.  In any case, almost any large-enough graph will give a counterexample.  Here's a small one: the triangle graph on vertices a, b and c.  The longest simple path from a to c is a-b-c; the longest simple path from c to b is c-a-b, so for the DP to work we must accept that the longest simple path from a to b is a-b-c-a-b -- but of course that path isn't simple.

Comment: @j_random_hacker In your third paragraph you made the claim so the burden of proof is actually on you. Also, I don't think that counts because the graph is cyclic. I'm talking about a non-cyclic graph with a simple path. In that case, the longest path problem DOES have the optimal substructure. Check out this answer http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56756/what-is-the-intuition-on-why-the-longest-path-problem-does-not-have-optimal-subs

Comment: @Ogen: Cyclic graphs "don't count"?  If you restrict the problem to forests (i.e., non-cyclic graphs) -- a restriction that you did **not** mention in your original comment -- then this problem, and nearly all graph problems, becomes substantially easier; but as it happens, it *still* does not possess the optimal substructure necessary for a direct DP solution: Consider the 4-vertex graph with edges ab, bc, bd.  The longest simple path from a to c is a-b-c; the longest simple path from c to d is c-b-d, but the longest simple path from a to d is not a-b-c-b-d because that path is not simple!

Comment: @Ogen: Secondly, Yuval Filmus's excellent answer does not contradict mine but rather *supports* it: read the paragraph in my answer beginning 'As a general rule, we can always "get around" this problem'.  My claim is that Longest Path does not possess the *same* (polynomially-many-states-having, and thus polynomial-time-solution-enabling) kind of optimal substructure that Shortest Path does.  Finally, regarding "burden of proof": If you want to use some idea for an algorithm, the burden is on *you* to prove that that idea always produces a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Simple Words : "**Principle of optimality states while solving the problem of optimization one has to solve sub-problems, solution of sub-problem will be the part of optimization problem**" , if problem can be solved by optimal sub problem means it consist optimal substructure.

Example : let say in a graph , source vertex is s and destination is d.
We have to find shortest(s,d)

```
    graph is
                a        g
                b   e    h                d
    s           c   f    i
                d   

length(s,a)=14
length(s,b)=10
length(s,c)=1
length(s,d)=6
length(c,b)=1
```

Note : No direct edge for (s,e) or (s,f).
While thinking to find an algo for this , if we are writing a priority queue structure which will traverse with least total PATH_Length .
We will assign each vertex PATH_LENGTH from source vertex.

we will keep assigning path_length to adjacent vertex if new path_length < existing path length.

```
Example : Len(s,b) > Len(s,a)+Len(a,b);
               reset len(s,b)=2;
```

Adjacent nodes from S creating a path to get minimal path_length irrespective of destination node,Because **they are making substructure that lead to solution**.